# Set a NSTimer in a AsynchronousRequest

Tags: objective-c, asynchronous, nstimer

In my app, I'm getting some data from my server. I need to refresh my data. 
I'm doing it in background using an asynchronous request.

What I'm doing (and I'm not sure if it is correct and/or recommended to do) is :

```
-(void)loadData
{
    //setting url request
    [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:urlRequest
                                       queue:[[NSOperationQueue alloc] init]
                           completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *resp, NSData *data, NSError *err)
    {
        //handling data
        myTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:interval 
                                                   target:self 
                                                 selector:@selector(loadData) 
                                                 userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
    }];
```

What I want to do is to wait for my data to be downloaded and handled, and then wait some times before refresh them. But this code does not work as I expect.

Where is my mistake?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: What does the colon after loadData mean? `-(void)loadData :` I am not positive that it compiles but it may change the selector from `loadData` to `loadData:` . And what exactly is the contents of `interval`. Did you try NSLoging it?

Comment: sorry, mistake of me when copying my code, there is no column after `loadData`. `interval` is a value that is set in my code (20.0 for example, but I replaced it here by `interval` because the problem does't come from here)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was summoned here as the author of SACompositeOperations.

Although every quoted string from SACompositeOperations is right (haha), SACompositeOperations is completely irrelevant to this question. Even if it was - it would then look like a usage of heavy artillery for such a simple task like loading of data in background.

@zbMax, I see that you are completely new to iOS development, so I suggest you the following:

Do not use `-[NSURLConnection asynchronousRequest:...]` for a job of fetching data in the background - read carefully the documentation of [AFNetworking library](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking) and immediatedly start using it instead of Apple's default NSURLConnection method. `AFNetworking` is a top level library, the whole world of iOS development uses it to deal with networking stuff.

Also, don't even think about using `NSTimer` in a way like you've described - actually don't use it at all. Just read carefuly how asynchronous requests are performed using AFNetworking.

Comment: Thank you for your link. I've founded many things in which will be useful for my project. BTW, I didn't find anything about loading a webview (if it is possible with this framework and more efficient)

Comment: You didn't mention a loading of a webview in your question in any way, that's why I've answered providing you with a general default. Regarding loading web views - general answer: "it depends". The most simple and the most probably right way of using it is to feed it just by using its -[UIWebView loadRequest:] method i.e. by feeding it with `NSURLRequest` objects pointing on the URLs of sources you might need.

Comment: Sorry, my previous comment is confusing. I mean : your reference is very helpful and solved my problem. I also found helpful stuff (like loading images for tableviewcell) and I was looking for functions to load web pages if they exist in this library. But it's another problem...

Comment: I don't want to misdirect you, better check AFNetworking yourself, but I don't remember any APIs regarding interactions with UIWebView. Good luck!